# What is the proper way to declare @BeforeClass on a test in Android with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, junit

I have an InstrumentedTest class like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MyInstrumentedTest {
    @Inject
    private lateinit var myVar:MyType

    @BeforeClass
    fun method(){
        with(myVar){
        ...
```

This gives an error because `method` must be static. If I put the @BeforeClass method inside a companion object and annotate with @JvmStatic, the injected myVar can't be used. Is there a more proper way to use the @BeforeClass using kotlin, in gereral and in this situation?

Comment: How do you inject your variable? Is it done in @Before method?

Comment: No, there is a Module with a Provider that has a MyType builder in the project

Answer (score 6):

Usage of companion object is the proper way:

```
companion object {
  @BeforeClass
  @JvmStatic
  fun setupClass() {
    // your class level setup logic here
  }
}
```

Remember that @BeforeClass is static and is executed before you have test object instance. There's no other way.
If you want to have access to the injected variable you should do your logic in @Before method which is executed before each @Test method.

```
  @Before
  fun setup() {
    // your setup logic here
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I had to do this inside @Before and used a control boolean to do the initialization code just once. Still, it is somewhat ugly

Comment: If it makes sense you could put your variable inside companion object as well so it's reachable from @‎BeforeClass method.
Not sure what you're trying to achieve but doing a setup for your test in @‎Before so it's executed before each test is completely normal use case (so each test has same starting state).
Also it is a good practice to clean up your state in @‎After method.

Comment: Actually I need to run this initialization code just once, as @BeforeClass runs just once it made sense. If I run everytime, it will break stuff, because it meddles with the database.